# File of json hashes into real json with Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have a text file (below) that is produced from a script that can not be altered. I am getting the file from the server and then I want to turn this "string" of json into real json using a ruby script...

Example of a file produced:

```
{"Key": "value", "Key2": "value2", "Key3": "value3"}
{"Key": "value", "Key2": "value2", "Key3": "value3"}
{"Key": "value", "Key2": "value2", "Key3": "value3"}
```

Note the lack of proper json formatting and lack of ANY commas... Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is it strictly one object per line?

Comment: Yes, it's always only one object per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the objects are one entry per line, you can do the following:

```
require 'json'

objects = $stdin.each_line.map { |line| JSON.parse(line) }
puts JSON.pretty_generate(objects)
```

Then just run `ruby clean.rb < log.txt > output.json`. For compact JSON, use `JSON.dump` instead of `JSON.pretty_generate`.

If you want to save a little time and memory by avoiding parsing and generating JSON, you can do the following:

```
prev = nil
print '['
$stdin.each_line do |line|
  print prev.strip + "," if prev
  prev = line
end
print prev.strip + ']'
```

A similar approach would be to use `sed` to append commas to each line and surround everything with brackets.

Comment: Prefer `each_line` to `read.lines` to avoid reading the entire file into memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `eval` to convert the string into a ruby hash. Here is a simple Ruby solution that does not require I/O redirection:

```
 require 'json'

 array_of_hashes = []
 File.open('hash.txt').each_line do |line|
   array_of_hashes << eval(line)
 end


 puts array_of_hashes.to_json
```

Returns:

```
 [{"Key":"value","Key2":"value2","Key3":"value3"},{"Key":"value","Key2":"value2","Key3":"value3"},{"Key":"value","Key2":"value2","Key3":"value3"}]
```